# Entropy change due to a growing plant

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Sunlight hitting a patch of the earth's surface causes the sun to lose entropy and the earth to gain entropy and there is a net gain in entropy (Delta S). But if that sunlight causes a plant to grow on that patch, then I'm not sure how to account for that entropy-wise. Is the growing plant (assume its 100 moles of carbon) decreasing Delta S? By how much?

Comment: Entropy always increases for a closed isolated system (there are extensions to that, but for now let's stay with that). Plus it is a property of the whole system. Thus local measures of entropy may increase or decrease, regardless.

Comment: The earth also loses entropy due to thermal radiation.  In the case of a plant, you need to forget about light hitting it and it receiving heat.  Instead you need to focus on the materials that eventually comprise the plant, and devise a reversible process for going from the initial thermodynamic state of these materials and the final thermodynamic state of a plant.  This will involve mostly chemical reactions.

Comment: @ChetMiller, Suppose I somehow calculate the entropy change due to the plant using the method you suggested and call that result as s_plant. My question is: 1) will s_plant be negative? 2) suppose I estimate the entropy of the plant as (number of particles)*(Boltzmann constant) as suggested by Schroeder's book. Will that be the same as s_plant?

Answer (score 2):

As a plant grows it converts many simple molecules (oxygen, carbon dioxide, water, nitrogen etc.) into a smaller number of more complex, molecules (cellulose, starch, chlorophyll, proteins etc.). The smaller set of complex molecules is more ordered than the larger set of simple molecules. Therefore the entropy of the plant itself is decreasing. This is true of all forms of life.

However, life can only decrease entropy locally by using energy from an external source, which increases in entropy by a greater amount. In most cases this ultimate source of energy and increasing entropy is the sun, although in some rare cases life gets its energy from the residual heat being released from the Earth's core.

Comment: In what sense is a cellulose or a chlorophyll molecule *more ordered* than say a $CO_2$ or an $H_2O$ molecule?

Comment: @hyportnex In the same way as a house of cards is more ordered than a random pile of cards and a cathedral is more ordered than a pile of rocks. If I throw a bunch of carbon dioxide and water molecules into a container I am very, very unlikely to see a chlorophyll or a cellulose molecule spontaneously assemble itself.

Comment: sure but your answer was about "a" molecule not a "pile" of molecules.

Comment: I upvoted but I would point out that phrasing entropy in terms of *order/disorder* is somewhat subjective and arbitrary (although common unfortunately). Each molecule has its own complexity and order not necessarily comparable as greater or lesser.

Comment: @hyportnex Not sure how you got that from my answer. Obviously a large number of simple molecules is assembled into a smaller number of more complex molecules and the smaller set of complex molecules are more ordered than the larger set of simple molecules. I have editted my answer to try to make this even clearer.

Comment: @NikosM. Order/disorder is not as subjective as you say. There are fewer ways to assemble a given number of hydrogen, carbon, oxygen etc. atoms into complex molecules like cellulose and chlorophyll than there are of assembling them into simple molecules like carbon dioxide and water. Therefore a set of complex molecules has more order/lower entropy than the equivalent set of simple molecules.

Comment: @gandalf61 I see your point but is not definitive. A molecule with 3 atoms arranged in angles can be more complex than a molecule with 5 atoms in a straight line. Really deciding between those involved many arbitrary assumptions. Hope you get the point.

Comment: The kind of reactions that happen in plants are basically *endothermic*. Processes that locally extract energy from the universe must represent a local decrease in entropy.